# How can I determine the size of a dump file prior to dumping?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, export, database-size

How can I determine or estimate the size of the SQL dump file prior to using something like mysqldump?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Please run this query:

```
SELECT
    Data_BB / POWER(1024,1) Data_KB,
    Data_BB / POWER(1024,2) Data_MB,
    Data_BB / POWER(1024,3) Data_GB
FROM (SELECT SUM(data_length) Data_BB FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql')) A;
```

This will give you a ballpark figure. The column `index_length` is not used because mysqldump does not dump indexes, only data. Just to be safe, you should always gzip it immediately:

```
mysqldump --all-databases --routines --triggers | gzip > MySQLData.sql.gz
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: The `A` in `A;`is no typo.

Comment: @Björn The `A` is an alias for the subquery.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Is there any way to exclude the index size from that count? I have rather large indices and they won't be taking room in the dump file.
Edit: I guess it would be SUM(DATA_LENGTH)-SUM(INDEX_LENGTH) DATA_BB

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi Please look carefully at my answer. I did exclude it already. Data pages and index pages are independent pages that coexist inside an `.ibd` file.

Comment: Thank you, ok so indexes are already excluded.

Comment: Great solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answer, if you want a one liner to determine the size in bytes to use in a shell script, you can use this:

```
mysqlSizeBytes="$(mysql --database=information_schema --skip-column-names --silent --execute "SELECT Data_BB FROM (SELECT SUM(data_length) Data_BB FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql')) A;")"
```