# Any way to estimate the required space for a SQL dump file?

Tags: mysql, import, xml, storage, dump

I want to import a Wikipedia XML dump file into MySQL. The uncompressed XML dump file is 65GB. Does this mean I should free up almost 64GB in the MySQL data path? Is there any way to estimate the required space?

Here is the sql schema:https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/HEAD/maintenance%2Ftables.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dealt with questions like this in both directions

- `Mar 20, 2013` : [How can I determine the size of a dump file prior to dumping?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37159/how-can-i-determine-the-size-of-a-dump-file-prior-to-dumping/37168#37168)
- `May 21, 2012` : [How large will a MySQL database be relative to the dump file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18220/how-large-will-a-mysql-database-be-relative-to-the-dump-file/18227#18227)

Your question is a little different because you did not give anything about the target MySQL Instance (what Storage Engine will be used, which columns are TEXT/BLOB, what indexing is needed for your data, etc.)

IMHO the most straightforward way I can think of is the following

### METHOD #1

Write some Perl/Python script to sum the length of all XML tag delimiters. Subtract the sum you get from the length of the file. That would essentially be the size of a CSV file less delimiters. This would be the bytes of the raw data.

### METHOD #2

Do METHOD #1 and also take the count of all XML tag delimiters and add that count to the result of METHOD #1. That would like adding commas back into a CSV file. This make be closer   in size to an actual CSV should you print the output to such a file.

Comment: If that schema was the result of converting the XML, simply remove all the comments. `I would estimate the data pages only from the dump size you get`. Indexes are built at the end of each tables load. If your indexes are properly designed to accommodate all your queries, then add another 20% of that figure.